# ExtJS form sended twice

Tags: forms, extjs, filter, extjs4, request

I have a form with search (filtering) fields like this:

```
xtype: 'form',
id: 'searchPanel',
title: 'Search',
collapsible: true,
bodyPadding: 10,

height: 210,
buttonAlign: 'left',
defaults: {
    width: 400,
    labelWidth: 120,
    allowBlank: true,
    enableKeyEvents: true        
},
layout: {
    type: 'table',
    columns: 2
},
items: [
    {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'txtFltrSiteName',
        fieldLabel: 'Site name or alias',
        id: 'txtFltrSiteName'
    },


    {
        xtype: 'textfield',
        name: 'txtMonthTraffic',
        fieldLabel: 'Month traffic',
        id: 'txtMonthTraffic',
        style: 'margin-left: 100px;'
    },

    {
        xtype: 'combo',
        id: 'ddlFltrPM',
        name: 'ddlFltrPM',
        fieldLabel: 'Project manager',
        displayField: 'display_name',
        valueField: 'user_id',
        editable: false,
        store: new storeOfUsers({ filters: [{ property: 'user_group_code', value: 'projectmanager', exactMatch: true }] })
    },

    // and many other fields below
```

But when i click on `search` button, i have two post request. One - with filter in it, second is without.

My code for `send` button action:

```
xtype: 'button',
id: 'btn_srch_set',
text: 'Searh',
margin: '10 7 0 0',
width: '',
handler: function() {       
    var filters = new Array();

    var site_name = Ext.getCmp('txtFltrSiteName').getValue();
    if(site_name.length > 0)
        filters.push({dataIndex: 'site_name', type: 'string', value: site_name}); 

    var project_name = Ext.getCmp('txtFltrProjectName').getValue();
    if(project_name.length > 0)
        filters.push({dataIndex: 'project_name', type: 'string', value: project_name});

    var pm = Ext.getCmp('ddlFltrPM').getValue();
    if(pm && pm > 0)    
        filters.push({dataIndex: 'project_manager_id', type: 'int', value: {'eq':pm}});

    // many other fields

    listOfSites.filters.removeAll();
    if(filters.length > 0)  
        listOfSites.filters.addFilters(filters);
    listOfSites.store.load(); 
}
```

**P.S.**
When I overwrite in `search` button handler function this line:

`filters.push({dataIndex: 'project_manager_id', type: 'string', value: pm});`

Evrything is ok and there is only one request, so problem might be here. But i'm stuck and have no idea why it works such way.

Thanks for any help,
Stanislav.

**UPD***

```
        var filters = {
        ftype: 'filters',
        // encode and local configuration options defined previously for easier reuse
        encode: true, // json encode the filter query
        local: false,
        filters: [{
            type: 'string',
            dataIndex: 'site_name'
        }, {
            type: 'date',
            dataIndex: 'startdate'
        }, {
            type: 'string',
            dataIndex: 'project_name'

        // more fields below
```

Comment: Can you tag your ExtJS version please?

Comment: Version is: **Ext JS 4**

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try following

```
if(filters.length > 0)  
    listOfSites.filters.addFilters(filters);
else
    listOfSites.store.load();
```

`addFilters()` may already call `sync()`

Comment: Oh! Thanks, it works! :) But for now.. filter is empty (there is no "filter" field in `post` data).

Comment: @StasGrin Wait a second, what is `filters`? I thought it is the store? Can you post it?

Comment: i'm talking about post data sended to my script, by clicking on 'search' button. so here is my post data for field `filter`: `"[{"type":"numeric","comparison":"eq","value":2,"field":"project_manager_id"},{"type":"string","value":"2","field":"client_id"}]"`

Comment: i looked through a JS file. there is no declaration of 'filters' in 'listofsites' object. but it is store, i guess.

Comment: @StasGrin OK. You have implemented a custom filtertype then? As far as I know ExtJS only supports `property` + `value` for remoteSort...

Comment: I updated post with `filters` declaration. I found it in other file.

Comment: @StasGrin It's hard for me to follow you cause `listOfSite` is now valid ExtJS object (at least I never found such). So it is hard to tell where you stuck. Basically filters get applied directly to the store and the store decides if he filters locally or remote

Comment: Ok, thanks for help. U make request disappear. I cant debug this one. So for now, I'm gonna further debug on "filters" variable to find *another answer*: "why it's empty". Thanks again.

Comment: and for filters used : `@class Ext.ux.grid.FiltersFeature` as i understood.

Comment: @StasGrin Yes, but there are many of these, at least for each type `Ext.ux.grid.filter.BooleanFilter` 
`Ext.ux.grid.filter.DateFilter` 
`Ext.ux.grid.filter.DateTimeFilter` 
`Ext.ux.grid.filter.ListFilter` 
`Ext.ux.grid.filter.NumericFilter` 
`Ext.ux.grid.filter.StringFilter`

Comment: Oh.. i'm such a newbie in ExtJS. I'm php developer. :( Sorry, for that poor questions. When I'll have a good another one, I'll ask again. Thank a lot for now :)